# Include apt.history.log in systemlog

Tags: apt, system, log

I am trying to find a way to Include apt.history.log in the systemlog so the logs will automatically be sent to a remote centralized log server I have running.

But is this something there is possible? I know yum does it by default

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `logger` command which is an interface to the system log module. It makes or writes one line entries in the system log file from the command line.

The general syntax is:

```
logger [options] [message]
```

For eg:

```
logger “Hello World”
```

will send the message "Hello World" to syslog. So in `tail /var/log/syslog` you should see:

```
Jan 31 20:13:50 ron ron: Hello World
```

You can also send the contents of a file with the `-f` option. From `man logger`:

```
-f, --file file
              Log the contents of the specified file.  This option  cannot  be
              combined with a command-line message.
```

You can use `logger` within a script; you just have to include the name of the script:

```
logger –t ScriptName “Hello World”
```

See `man logger` for more details. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117878/how-to-view-write-to-system-log-files-on-ubuntu/) are few nice [reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-write-to-syslog.html).

Comment: Quick question from here. Will I have to use a script to accomplishe this?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can write the whole thing to syslog before you sent it to remote server. But if you want to automate this it might require a script (or a cronjob perhaps?)